# Pull request conflict

Tags: git

I have used another developer branch because I need to make some changes in that branch.
then, I made some changes and pushed to my branch. then, I created a pull request bitbucket. now, it's showing conflict. then, I have deleted that pull request.
I also noticed in the pull request that my changes and other developer changes are mixed.
now, I have to create the pull request again.
can someone please help me, what should I do before creating the pull request.

Comment: You need to improve your question and be clear with the term "stash". Because this sentence in your question " pushed to stash. then, I created a pull request in the stash" doesn't make sense. A git stash cannot have a pull request function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that you're merging the PR to the master branch:

1. locally switch to master - `git checkout master`
2. pull - `git pull`
3. switch back to your branch - `git checkout <yourBranch>`
4. rebase onto master in order to get all the changes that have been done to the master branch into your branch - `git rebase master`
5. You will receive a notification that there are conflicts and you have to resolve them
6. Resolve the conflicts in whatever git editor your use (intellij has stuff for conflict resolution already built-in, but you can as well edit stuff even in vi)
7. once all conflicts are resolved finish the rebase - `git rebase continue`
8. push everything to the branch - `git push --force` (note that forcing is mandatory after rebasing if your branch is already available on the remote server)

Comment: Typo: it should read `git rebase --continue`. And as an aside, it might be preferable to always run [`git push --force-with-lease`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-force-with-lease) instead of `git push -f`. (see also the repo [git tips](https://github.com/git-tips/tips#forced-push-but-still-ensure-you-dont-overwrite-others-work))